# How were these SDE derived?

Tags: stochastic-calculus

Can anyone give me a detailed explanation of how below equations (3) and (4) are derived from (1) and (2)?
\begin{align*}
\frac{dF_{t,T}}{F_{t,T}} &=\sigma e^{-\lambda(T-t)}dB_t, \tag{1}\\
\ln(F_{t,T})&=\ln(F_{0,T})-1/2\int_{0}^{t}\sigma^2 e^{-2\lambda(T-s)}ds+\int_{0}^{t}\sigma e^{-\lambda(T-s)}dB_s.\tag{2}
\end{align*}
Given $\ln(S_t)=\ln(F_{t,t})$, we have:
\begin{align*}
\frac{dS_t}{S_t}=(\mu_t-\lambda \ln(S_t))dt+\sigma dB_t,\tag{3}
\end{align*}
where
\begin{align*}
\mu_t=\frac{\partial \ln(F_{0,t})}{\partial t} +\lambda \ln(F_{0,t})+\frac{1}{4}\sigma^2(1-e^{-2\lambda t}). \tag{4}
\end{align*}
Or anything related to them will be helpful.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From $(2)$, 
\begin{align*}
\ln S_t &=\ln F_{t, t} \\
&= \ln F_{0, t}-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^t\sigma^2 e^{-2\lambda (t-s)}ds+\int_0^t \sigma e^{-\lambda(t-s)} dB_s\\
&=\ln F_{0, t}-\frac{\sigma^2}{4\lambda} \left(1-e^{-2\lambda t}\right)+e^{-\lambda t}\int_0^t \sigma e^{\lambda s} dB_s.
\end{align*}
Then,
\begin{align*}
\lambda e^{-\lambda t}\int_0^t \sigma e^{\lambda s} dB_s = \lambda \ln S_t - \lambda \ln F_{0, t} + \frac{\sigma^2}{4} \left(1-e^{-2\lambda t}\right).
\end{align*}
Therefore,
\begin{align*}
d\ln S_t &= \left(\frac{\partial \ln F_{0, t}}{\partial t}-\frac{\sigma^2}{2}e^{-2\lambda t} - \lambda e^{-\lambda t}\int_0^t \sigma e^{\lambda s} dB_s\right)dt +\sigma dB_t\\
&=\left[\frac{\partial \ln F_{0, t}}{\partial t}-\frac{\sigma^2}{2}e^{-2\lambda t}+\lambda \ln F_{0, t} - \frac{\sigma^2}{4} \left(1-e^{-2\lambda t}\right) -\lambda \ln S_t\right]dt + \sigma dB_t\\
&=\left(\frac{\partial \ln F_{0, t}}{\partial t}+\lambda \ln F_{0, t} -\frac{\sigma^2}{4} - \frac{\sigma^2}{4} e^{-2\lambda t} -\lambda \ln S_t\right)dt + \sigma dB_t.
\end{align*}
Note that 
\begin{align*}
d\langle \ln S, \ln S \rangle_t= \sigma^2 dt. 
\end{align*}
By Ito's lemma,
\begin{align*}
dS_t &= de^{\ln S_t}\\
&= e^{\ln S_t} d \ln S_t + \frac{1}{2}e^{\ln S_t}d\langle \ln S, \ln S \rangle_t\\
&=S_t d \ln S_t + \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2 S_t dt\\
&= S_t\left[\left(\frac{\partial \ln F_{0, t}}{\partial t}+\lambda \ln F_{0, t} -\frac{\sigma^2}{4} - \frac{\sigma^2}{4} e^{-2\lambda t} -\lambda \ln S_t\right)dt + \sigma dB_t + \frac{\sigma^2}{2} dt \right]\\
&=S_t\big[\left(\mu_t - \lambda \ln S_t\right)dt + \sigma dB_t\big],
\end{align*}
where
\begin{align*}
\mu_t = \frac{\partial \ln F_{0, t}}{\partial t}+\lambda \ln F_{0, t} +\frac{\sigma^2}{4}\left(1- e^{-2\lambda t}\right).
\end{align*}