# Ito's Lemma, differentiating an integral with Brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-calculus, itos-lemma

In [How were these SDE derived?](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/27614/how-were-these-sde-derived) I don't understand one part of Gordon's answer, specifically:

$$\ln S_t=\ln F_{0,t}-\frac{\sigma^2}{4\lambda}(1-e^{-2\lambda t})+\sigma e^{-\lambda t}\int_0^t e^{\lambda s}dB_s$$
$$d\ln S_t=\bigg(\frac{\partial \ln F_{0,t}}{\partial t}-\frac{\sigma^2 }{2}e^{-2\lambda t}-\lambda \sigma e^{-\lambda t}\int_0^t e^{\lambda s}dB_s\bigg)dt+\sigma dB_t$$

My question is, how to get from the first line to the second. Evidently, Ito's Lemma was applied, however it has been used in a way in which I have not encountered. It seems that the integral with the Brownian motion term was treated as a constant, but I don't see how that is allowed when there is $t$ in the upper limit.

Any help is appreciated.

Edit: I have come up with a solution, as long as the following is valid. Can anyone please confirm? The first line uses the product rule.
\begin{align}
d\bigg(\sigma e^{-\lambda t}\int_0^t e^{-\lambda s}dB_s\bigg)&=d(\sigma e^{-\lambda t})\int_0^t e^{-\lambda s}dB_s+\sigma e^{-\lambda t}d\bigg(\int_0^t e^{\lambda s}dB_s\bigg)\\
&=-\lambda\sigma e^{-\lambda t}dt \int_0^t e^{-\lambda s}dB_s+\sigma e^{-\lambda t}e^{\lambda t}dB_t\\
&=-\lambda\sigma e^{-\lambda t}dt \int_0^t e^{-\lambda s}dB_s+\sigma dB_t
\end{align}

Comment: If we differentiate $\sigma e^{-\lambda t}\int_0^t e^{\lambda s} dB_s$ we just use the multiplication rule and the fact that $\frac{d}{dx} \int_0^t x(s) dB_s = x(t) dB_t $ if we assume some reasonable restrictions on $x$. 
Your edit gets the exponential wrong in the second part, it is $e^{\lambda t}$ without the '-'.

Comment: Very clear, thanks. Fixed the exponential as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right in your use of product rule.

Since $\sigma e^{-\lambda t}$ is a finite variation process, you do not have crochet term and this is the standard product rule.

In your second line, there is an extra $t$ (which is a typo I presume)

$$\ln S_t=\ln F_{0,t}-\frac{\sigma^2}{4\lambda}(1-e^{-2\lambda t})+\sigma e^{-\lambda t}\int_0^t e^{\lambda s}dB_s$$
$$d\ln S_t=\bigg(\frac{\partial \ln F_{0,t}}{\partial t}-\frac{\sigma^2 }{2}e^{-2\lambda t}-\lambda \color{red}{t}\sigma e^{-\lambda t}\int_0^t e^{\lambda s}dB_s\bigg)dt+\sigma dB_t$$
the correct equation is:
$$d\ln S_t=\bigg(\frac{\partial \ln F_{0,t}}{\partial t}-\frac{\sigma^2 }{2}e^{-2\lambda t}-\lambda \sigma e^{-\lambda t}\int_0^t e^{\lambda s}dB_s\bigg)dt+\sigma dB_t$$

Comment: Excellent, fixed the typo.